# latest EOSJS (20.0.0-beta2): missing node_modules/eosjs/lib/index.js?

Tags: eosjs

Trying to import latest build of EOSJS but getting error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../node_modules/eosjs/lib/index.js'
```

previous versions 'work' until I try to access the Rpc.JsonRpc module (gives "cannot read property 'JsonRpc' of undefined")

any ideas? I can see in the eosjs folder in node modules there isn't even a lib folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
import JsonRpc from 'eosjs/dist/eosjs-jsonRpc.js'
```